# Do import.io crawlers obey robots.txt?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, import.io

When you run an [import.io](http://import.io) crawler, does it obey to the `robots.txt` file?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the faq](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/265494-crawler-faq), it turns out it does.

> Do you adhere to robots.txt?
>   **Yes**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we do (also with Extractors and Connectors)